# PHP / MySQL Getting and processing data totals, counts efficently

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have to create a few functions for a website that will get a lot of data from a MySQL database, process it in a number of ways and produce tables/graphs in HTML and excel format but do not know what the most efficient way of getting, storing and processing the data would be in PHP.

Up till now I've just used PHP to submit SQL statements which return rows and then go into objects that I call relevant information from, but the new functions could return up to 18,000 rows which I need to get averages, counts, etc from.

It seems I have to either make a bunch of SQL statements for the counts / averages or use PHP to do something similar. I would need to go through the 18,000 rows up to 20 times. Which would be the preferable way or does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: Unless you provide more details, it will be hard for us to tell you anything. Most of averages and counts, for instance, can be done inside SQL so you will get your summary already in PHP and do what you always do ;) There is no magical solution on "what to do with a lot of data in PHP". Every task in hand has its own solution (or multiple sometimes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever possible use mysql's in-built functions for processing data. Normally mysql functions like avg, count are much efficient compared to php